# How to extract including data with group by

Tags: pandas

```
|id|name|state|
|1|A|yes|
|2|B|yes|
|3|B|no|
|4|C|yes|
|5|C|yes|
|6|D|no|
```

When I define above Dataframe using df.groupby(['name']).
I would like to extract the name item with 'yes' at state.

In case of this, A, B, C is target data to extract.

How can I extract that data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extract values by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`Series.unique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unique.html) and filter again by [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
a = df.loc[df['state'] == 'yes', 'name'].unique()
print (a)
['A' 'B' 'C']

df1 = df[df['name'].isin(a)]
print (df1)
   id name state
0   1    A   yes
1   2    B   yes
2   3    B    no
3   4    C   yes
4   5    C   yes
```

Another solution is use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with [`GroupBy.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.any.html) for test at least one `True` per group:

```
df1 = df[(df['state'] == 'yes').groupby(df['name']).transform('any')]
print (df1)
   id name state
0   1    A   yes
1   2    B   yes
2   3    B    no
3   4    C   yes
4   5    C   yes
```